# How to retrieve sum of a column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sum

Hi I have a query in PHP that calculates the sum of all the values in a column. However when I try to print, nothing happens. I get a blank page. Im pretty sure its an obvious problem but constant coding means I cant think straight :(

```
$query = 'SELECT SUM(cost) AS total_price FROM items WHERE item_ID = $input';
$sum = mysql_query($query, $database);

$row = mysql_fetch_row($sum);

echo "Total "" = $". $row['total_price'];
```

Comment: What happens if you print your query and try to execute that query in mysql directly? Perhaps $input is empty?

Comment: If `$input` is a PHP variable, the first line should be using double quotes.

Comment: At the very least consider using [mysqli_](http://php.net/mysqli) functions instead of the mysql_ functions. The mysql_ functions are considered outdated and the announcement to deprecate them was announced quite a while ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) fetches a enumerated array, you want [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

Alternatively you can just use [`mysql_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) to fetch the single field.

---

You also have a syntax error in your echo which would cause a blank page unless you have `error_reporting`/`display_errors` on:

```
echo "Total "" = $". $row['total_price'];
```

should be:

```
echo "Total = $". $row['total_price'];
```

Comment: @Matt9Atkins try `echo mysql_num_rows($sum);` to see if any result return

Comment: @safarov theres nothing printing

Comment: I fixed the syntax error. Now all that prints is "Total = $" The value is missing

Comment: What is `$input`? Are you sure there's any items with the item_ID equal to `$input`? *Edit:* Didn't notice that, as @halfer said in the comments, you also need to use double quotes not single quotes for `$query` so `$input` gets expanded.

Comment: $input is a text box. I have tried mock codes to check it reads from the box correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$query = 'SELECT SUM(cost) AS total_price FROM items WHERE item_ID = $input';
$sum = mysql_query($query, $database) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($sum) > 0)  {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sum);
    echo 'Total  = $'.$row['total_price'];
} else {
    echo "No result found";
}
```

Comment: it gives me the last column, not the total